# Getting Logitech USB headset to work on Debian

Tags: usb, debian, alsa, headset

I am attempting to get a Logitech USB headset to work on my Debian Squeeze computer. However, no matter what I do, there is no sound. I've already tried everything I could find on Google with no luck.

Originally, `cat /proc/asound/cards` listed the internal card in slot 0 and my headset in slot 1. After following the suggestion to rename `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko` so it can't be found, it no longer reports the internal card, but my headset is still in slot 1.

I also tried editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to comment out the last line and add `options snd-usb-audio index=1`, but nothing I did to this file had any effect. I also tried rebooting the computer in between each change, but that didn't help.

Update: I reenabled the `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko` module, so both the internal card and the headset showed up.

Then I installed PulseAudio using the directions at http://zitzlinuxblog.blogspot.com/2010/10/this-is-updated-version-of-how-to-i_07.html, but this only made things worse! Now the only thing that shows up under sound preferences and pavucontrol is "Dummy Output".

So what can I do? I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Why are you setting `index=1` when you want it to be at index 0? Why aren't you just selecting the headset in the PulseAudio configuration?

Comment: Because that's what I found online suggested. Anyway, I'm not sure how to do the PulseAudio thing but I'll look into it.

Comment: @CL What do you mean by "selecting the headset in the PulseAudio configuration"? How do I do that?

Comment: Something like [pavucontrol](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/)'s configuration tab.

Comment: @CL I installed PulseAudio, but that only made things worse! Now the only thing that shows up under System Sound Preferences and Pavucontrol is "Dummy Output".

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

Run `sudo alsamixer` in a terminal, press F6 and select your headset.

If you have selected it, check that the volume bar does not have "MM" on it.
If it does, it's muted. Use the 'M' key to unmute it.

Comment: I no longer have the headphones or the computer in question, so it's a bit obsolete. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Didn't realize this was asked 3 years ago, sorry.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to answer old questions! We always welcome people to share their solutions.